# How to create interfaces for CSR 1000v for GRE tunnels?

Tags: cisco, routing, interface, tunnel

Well, my idea is to connect to 4 `CSR 1000v` routers in different VPC (without VPC peering).
I've basically finished with everything with the pre-configuration *creating VPCs, subnets IGW, modifying Route Tables ... etc*. Then, using `IPsec over GRE tunnels`, the 4 instances can see each other. *(Thanks to @MLu for suggesting this idea [How to do routing between the instances in AWS using Route Table?](https://serverfault.com/questions/942805/how-to-do-routing-between-the-instances-in-aws-using-route-table)
)*.

After having 4 instances and each of them their Primary Network Interfaces is associated with public IP addresses *(`52.37.168.182` is for `CSR1` and `3.41.68.82` is for `CSR2`)*. I saw this video where I almost have the same configuration [YouTube Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PtK8HgkRvM).  I started to configure the tunnel between 2 `CSRs 1000v` routers, where I created an interface inside the router called `Tunnel 0` with its source interface  which is here `GigabitEthernet 1` so my configuration is the following:

```
CSR1(config)#interface tunnel 0
CSR1(config-if)#tunnel source GigabitEthernet 1
CSR1(config-if)#tunnel destination 52.37.168.182

CSR2(config)#interface tunnel 0
CSR2(config-if)#tunnel source GigabitEthernet 1
CSR2(config-if)#tunnel destination 3.41.68.82
```

Then I configured the IP addresses of these both tunnels' interfaces as it shows in the figure below.

```
CSR1(config)#int tun 0
CSR1(config-if)#ip address 10.10.1.2 255.255.255.252

CSR2(config)#int tun 0
CSR2(config-if)#ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
```

[image]

My problem now is that the status of these tunnels' interfaces are `down` as it shows `show ip int br`:

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status           Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.0.1.10      YES DHCP   up                  up
Tunnel0                10.10.1.1       YES manual up                 down    
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                  up
```

I realized that I have to create a subnet for the tunnel which I did at the end `10.10.1.0/28` then I created other interfaces in all instances.

My idea is to attach those new interfaces with a generated public IP address then I will get a new interface which is `GigabitEthernet 2` obviously, and I continue the configuration using this new interface `GigabitEthernet 2` instead of `Tunnel 0`. Can I do the same configuration for tunnels in GigabitEthernet interfaces? I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: you have to make sure your tunnel sources have ip reachibilty to each other. can you ping 3.41.68.82 from 52.37.168.182 ? you also might need to configure the default route to your GW if you have not done it yet.

Comment: @NANIS the ping is successful, the tunnel is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort the problem out. When setting up the public for the interface source, GRE tunneling is mixing up with the NAT. Therefore, I used IPIP mode, and the problem is solved.